# 'NoneType' object is not iterable after PyInstaller app creation on a Mac

Tags: django, macos, django-models, django-forms, pyinstaller

I have a working piece of code which runs fine.

Here's the model:

```
class Therapist(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    SEX_CHOICES = (
      ('M','male'),
      ('F','female'),
    )
    sex = EncryptedCharField(choices = SEX_CHOICES, blank=False, max_length=20, verbose_name = "Płeć")
    company = models.ManyToManyField(Company, blank=True, verbose_name = "Firma")
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription, blank=False, verbose_name = "Abonament")
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=False, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
```

The form:

```
class MyRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    SEX_CHOICES = (
        ('F', 'kobieta'),
        ('M', 'mężczyzna'),
    )
    first_name = forms.CharField(label="Imię")
    last_name = forms.CharField(label="Nazwisko")
    user_email = forms.EmailField(label="Adres e-mail")
    user_sex = forms.ChoiceField(label="Wybierz swoją płeć", choices = SEX_CHOICES)
    username = forms.CharField(label="Nazwa użytkownika")
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Wpisz hasło", widget = PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Powtórz hasło", widget = PasswordInput())

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # this is to verify if any user exists at all. If yes - do not allow other users to be created!
            if Therapist.objects.all().exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'Jakiś użytkownik już istnieje, a Twoja wersja programu nie pozwala na tworzenie więcej niż 1 użytkownika. Wersje dla więcej niż jednego terapeuty dostępne pod kontakt@zapiszsesje.pl'), code='invalid')
            else:
                return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(u'Użytkownik o nazwie "%s" już istnieje.' % username)

    def clean_user_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['user_email']
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email =email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError(u'Użytkownik o takim adresie email już istnieje.')
```

& the view:

```
def myRegistrationView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username = form.cleaned_data['username'],
                email = form.cleaned_data['user_email'],
                password = form.cleaned_data['password1'],
                first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
                last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
                )
            user.save()

            subscription = Subscription(
               expired_on = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = 90)
            )
            subscription.save()

            therapist = Therapist(
                user = user,
                sex = form.cleaned_data['user_sex'],
                subscription = subscription,
            )
            therapist.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('registration_gotowe'))
else:
    form = MyRegistrationForm()

param = {
    'form':form
    }
return render(request, 'registration/registration_form.html', param)
```

When I package the app using a Mac and PyInstaller the app works fine until I get to that view and try to register creating a User, Subscription and Therapist. In that moment I get a

`TypeError at /konto/register/
'NoneType' object is not iterable` error ...

The same code works fine on Windows before and after the PyInstaller compilation to an exe file. Apart from that the app seems to work fine without any errors.

If I comment out the part of the code where the Therapist is created in the view:

```
therapist = Therapist(
                user = user,
                sex = form.cleaned_data['user_sex'],
                subscription = subscription,
            )
            therapist.save()
```

the app 'works' fine - this error does not occur....

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace or the entire error page? It's hard to guess what could be going wrong with just that much. My guess would be on `company` not being passed to the Therapist but the should probably throw an error even on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I found out that the Company model is causing this error - potentially due to django-fernet not being correctly imported by pyInstaller. I will close this question and likely open a new one. Thanks!